# Как проверить открыто ли окно в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как проверить открыто ли окно в WPF? Когда окно открыто, то при нажатии на кнопу открывается новое окно. Как предотвратить это?

Как проверить открытоли окно в WPF?

```
public void SecondWindow()
{
    myWin mw = new myWin();
    mw.Show();
}
```

PS. Проблему решил следующим образом. Вместо mw.Show(); нужно написать mw.ShowDialog();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202101/how-do-i-know-if-a-wpf-window-is-opened

Comment: Дмитрий, Спасибо! Проблему решил.